# How to avoid mouse move on Touch

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I have a WPF application that is capable of being used both with a mouse and using Touch. I disable all windows "enhancements" to just have touch events :

```
Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"
Stylus.IsTapFeedbackEnabled="False"
Stylus.IsTouchFeedbackEnabled="False"
Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False"
```

The result is that a click behave like I want except on two points :

- The small "touch" cursor (little white star) appears where clicked an when dragging. 
  Completely useless as the user finger is already at this location no feedback is required (Except my element potentially changing color if actionable).
- Elements stay in the "Hover" state after the movement / Click ends.

Both are the consequences of the fact that while windows transmit correctly touch events, he still move the mouse to the last main-touch-event.

I don't want windows to move the mouse at all when I use touch inside my application. Is there a way to completely avoid that?

Notes:

- Handling touch events change nothing to this.
- Using SetCursorPos to move the mouse away make the cursor blink and isn't really user-friendly.
- Disabling the touch panel to act as an input device completely disable all events (And I also prefer an application-local solution, not system wide).
- I don't care if the solution involve COM/PInvoke or is provided in C/C++ i'll translate.
- If it is necessary to patch/hook some windows dlls so be it, the software will run on a dedicated device anyway.
- I'm investigating the surface SDK but I doubt that it'll show any solution. As a surface is a pure-touch device there is no risk of bad interaction with the mouse.

Comment: After digging down it doesn't seem that it is possible only for my window but using SetWindowsHookEx i could do it globally. I'll be ok for now to enable this when my app goes full screen. i'll post the solution when i have something clean.

Comment: If anyone (say from Microsoft) happen to have a better solution, feel free to post.

Comment: I do not know if it is sufficient to you to, but you can find out if a mouse event was promoted by a touch by checking if (e.StylusDevice != null).

Comment: Take a look at this one. It worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19540120/690656

Comment: I no longer work with touch screens and Win 8 wasn't released at the time so there may be solutions now. But note that I WANTED MOUSE PROMOTION (So I wanted touch events to act like mouse events in WPF), I just wanted it to happens without visibly affecting the windows cursor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Here is the best solution I found from now. Don't hesitate to post your own, especially if it is better.*

Using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) low level mouse event catching (`WH_MOUSE_LL`) and the fact that all events converted from Touch to Mouse are marked as such (The `MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH` flag is set in the event's ExtraInfo, see [Microsoft's FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd693088%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) I was able to **Globally** remove all mouse events comming from the touch panel.

It isn't an ideal solution but it'll do for now in my application when it is running fullscreen (99% of the time as it is a dedicated hardware device).

The second step also good only in fullscreen (That i won't provide code for as it is pretty simple) is just moving the mouse to "safe" position like the bottom right of the screen with [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you need the code it is in [a Gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/1339671) and i'll post the current version at the end of this article. To use it :

```
// As long as the instance is alive the conversion won't occur
var disableTouchMouse = new DisableTouchConversionToMouse();

// To let the conversion happen again, Dispose the class.
disableTouchMouse.Dispose();
```

Full source code of the class :

```
namespace BlackFox
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;

    /// <summary>
    /// As long as this object exists all mouse events created from a touch event for legacy support will be disabled.
    /// </summary>
    class DisableTouchConversionToMouse : IDisposable
    {
        static readonly LowLevelMouseProc hookCallback = HookCallback;
        static IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

        public DisableTouchConversionToMouse()
        {
            hookId = SetHook(hookCallback);
        }

        static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            var moduleHandle = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(null);

            var setHookResult = UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, moduleHandle, 0);
            if (setHookResult == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            return setHookResult;
        }

        delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                var info = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

                var extraInfo = (uint)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt32();
                if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_MASK) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                {
                    if((extraInfo & 0x80) != 0)
                    {
                        //Touch Input
                        return new IntPtr(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Pen Input
                        return new IntPtr(1);
                    }

                }
            }

            return UnsafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        bool disposed;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed) return;

            UnsafeNativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
            disposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ~DisableTouchConversionToMouse()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        #region Interop

        // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        // ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Local
        // ReSharper disable FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local

        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MASK = 0xFFFFFF00;

        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH = 0xFF515700;
        const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct POINT
        {

            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        static class UnsafeNativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod,
                uint dwThreadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
                IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        }

        // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
        // ReSharper restore FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local
        // ReSharper restore MemberCanBePrivate.Local

        #endregion
    }
}
```

edit: From the comments section of [Troubleshooting Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd693088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [System Events and Mouse Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) additional information to disambiguate pen from touch.

Comment: We have to find application-wide solution... Most touch applications does not have dedicated hardware device.
Also "bottom right corner" is absolutely not a safe place, since in windows 7+ it hides all windows on hover. And in Windows 8 all corners have their meaning. Try to find Max (Min) value of Right (Left) property from collections of monitors, and add some more pixels to hide a cursor (do not forget to translate pixels to DIP depending on API)

Comment: I also had to hard-reboot my tablet PC after this suggestion (didn't understood completely what means 'global' here). Since I had been unable to close my app with this hack...

Comment: Well I didn't find any solution local to an application. As said my solution was global and my app was full screen and running on Win7 (So bottom right is a safe spot because I decided so in my app and didn't put anything there)

Comment: This solution causes crashes in my case. Windows 8.1, .net 4.5.1

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia is this approach also suitable for windows 8.1 over .NET Framework 4.6?

Comment: Change the ToInt32 to ToInt64 when the extraInfo variable is declared in HookCallback to prevent crashing in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: In my tests (running under Windows 7), touch-events that get converted to mouse-events are NOT reported under `WH_MOUSE_LL`. I rewrote the code to use `WH_MOUSE` instead, and I see the mouse-events being generated from the touch events, and I return `new IntPtr(1)`...but the converted mouse-events are still setting the position of the Windows mouse pointer. So far, it doesn't seem possible to have two separate windows on the same computer, one interacted with by touch, one interacted with by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Something I used for an application once, was to simply setup a custom cursor whose image was simply a blank .CUR file.

As for the second problem, I would have indeed suggested moving the cursor to another location, but then I saw you'd done the same thing. If you application won't run in full screen, you can just define that safe position to be the lower-right corner of your application window.

Comment: Well, the problem with the blank cursor is that I don't want my application to be unusable with a mouse, it should work ok with a mouse as the user is free to connect one to the device. Also Windows 7 create the "white star" cursor on touch and it isn't configurable (it always display and ignore any application defined one)

Comment: I see what you mean. There is this one [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-the-touch-pointer-on-or-off) which suggests it might be possible to turn it off. What I don't know is whether it's disabled or just hidden. If just hidden, I suppose that option could be accessed programatically (worst case, based on finding out where it is in the registry). What I'm thinking is you could enable/disable it based on whether your application window is in foreground. Would that makes sense?

Comment: Actually i tried this options and what it does is not controlling the small white star pointer but enabling / disabling an even more horrible "cursor" where a mouse picture is displayed on the left of where your click and you could click on it's button to simulate a click. It's off by default and seeing how crappy it looks it shouldn't exists at all :-D

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I have any other ideas for now :(.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear to me if you actually want to avoid touch promotion to mouse or not, since you first ask about how to avoid moving the mouse cursor from touch, but then in a comment you explicitly say that you do want mouse promotion.

If you want to avoid mouse promotion, I posted an answer that works from Windows 8 and later [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814536/6059640).

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same problem and I found out [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b05e550-19c0-46a2-b19c-40f40c8bf0ec/prevent-a-wpf-application-to-interpret-touch-events-as-mouse-events?forum=wpf) that one can use the PreviewXXX events to determine if the event was initiated by touch or by mouse input. Have a look at the following code:

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StylusDevice != null)
    {
        AddInfoItem("Stylus or Touch recognized");
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    AddInfoItem("No Stylus or Touch recognized");
}
```

You can check the `StylusDevice` property of the `MouseEventArgs` to determine if a touch event was involved previously. If it is not null, you can set `e.Handled` to true to prevent that the event that corresponds to the PreviewXXX event is being raised.

Hope that helps. A demo project for this can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qq6o56yupxpfykw/PreventMouseEventsAfterTouch.zip) (Dropbox link).

Comment: I didn't want to suppress them at all, I wanted them to act EXACTLY as normal. Except that they didn't show the ugly white star and didn't make the control say in the hover state.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Shall I delete my answer?