# Disable mouse promotion

Tags: wpf, windows, touch, mouse

Is there any way to disable mouse promotion from code, that is preventing windows to interpret touch events as mouse events?

I capture touch events in my WPF application, and I don't want these interactions to effect mouse pointer visibility and position.

There is a [TouchFrameEventArgs.SuspendMousePromotionUntilTouchUp Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchframeeventargs.suspendmousepromotionuntiltouchup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that seems to be doing exactly that. Unfortunately it's available only for Silverlight and Windows Phone.

In addition there are some system settings you can use to disable double click and right click promotion, but nothing to disable mouse promotion as a whole.

A Windows 8 specific solution or a low level solution would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any such option (at least up to Windows 8.1 and .NET 4.5).

The only way to disable mouse promotion is to disable finger input completely, either from within the system control panel (open control panel, open "Pen and Touch", select "Touch" tab, disbale "Use your finger as an input device") or via Registry (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch, TouchGate = 0 =disable touch)

Then you can still process touch input using one of the following (nasty) alternatives:

- Write your own [WinUSB driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your touch device
- Get raw touch input data using the [RawInput API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Find a 3rd party USB driver for your device (e.g. [UPDD TouchBase](http://touch-base.com/documentation.asp))

Finally, you can inject the collected touch data into your application using [custom routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx) or using [touch injection](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Touch-Injection-Sample-444d9bf7).

In any case you will, of course, loose touch support for any other application on your system, so this solution will in general not be too helpfull to you.

Answer (score 3):

The plain Win32 API way of disabling touch promotion to mouse is to handle `WM_POINTER*` messages in your window's [`WindowProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633573) (actually, it seems just [`WM_POINTERDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputmsg/wm-pointerdown) is enough) and NOT call `DefWindowProc()`.

This is what we actually do in some of our commercial applications, and what is suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3fb9c779-fa9f-4b11-9b59-8003edb7d014/how-to-hook-touch-message-and-block-mouse-message?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues#b77825a1-804b-4389-9391-9951e34f44f7-isAnswer).

This is ONLY available from Windows 8 and later, since the `WM_POINTER*` messages are not generated by Windows 7 and below.

Now, in the WPF world, this gets more complicated.

First of all, in order to get proper `WM_POINTER*` handling by the WPF stack, you first need to

- Use .NET 4.7
- [Change some configuration in your WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/mitigation-pointer-based-touch-and-stylus-support):

(Reporting the code here, just in case the MS page disappears) You need to insert this in your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.EnablePointerSupport=true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now the new shiny WPF stack is activated, but it's bugged and moves the mouse cursor even if you handle the [`OnTouchDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ontouchdown), [`OnTouchUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ontouchup), [`OnTouchMove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ontouchmove) events and set the [`Handled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled) flag to true.

We discovered, through the use of a [`HwndSourceHook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsourcehook) and blocking the [`WM_POINTERDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputmsg/wm-pointerdown) message, that the mouse cursor was finally staying still (although we were blocking all touch-down interactions!)

So, we deducted that the shiny new WPF is actually calling `DefWindowProc`, even if we are handling the `OnTouch*` events.

Our soultion was to use [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/), in order to intercept the `DefWindowProc` call, and block the `WM_POINTERDOWN` from reaching the real `DefWindowProc`.

The detour code is:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>

static LRESULT(WINAPI * _originalDefWindowProcA)(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = DefWindowProcA;
static LRESULT(WINAPI * _originalDefWindowProcW)(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = DefWindowProcW;

static LRESULT WINAPI myDefWindowProcA(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_POINTERDOWN:
        return 0;
    
    default:
        return _originalDefWindowProcA(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

static LRESULT WINAPI myDefWindowProcW(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_POINTERDOWN:
        return 0;

    default:
        return _originalDefWindowProcW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

void SetupDefWindowProcDetour()
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)_originalDefWindowProcA, myDefWindowProcA);
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)_originalDefWindowProcW, myDefWindowProcW);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
}
```

NOTE: `SetupDefWindowProcDetour` must be called by the main (UI) thread of your app.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for back in 2013. Unfortunately I cannot confirm the solution, as the project has been archived years ago. Too sad, something that simple needs workarounds like this.

Comment: I not understand what and where put that portion of c++ code.
My project is C# wpf,  please gog, can explain more?

Comment: For sure, apologize, I have no idea of c++ ; (

Comment: @MrBi in order to use that code (which is plain C) from C# code, you need to put that in a C++/CLI mixed mode DLL, maybe in a class as static methods, and than use that static methods from your C# code.
You really first need to learn C++/CLI (which is a .NET extension to C++) and mixed-mode DLLs in .NET. More than that, this is using the Detours library, which is doing really weird stuff in assembly language to tweak existing system functions. It can insanely break things, especially if you mix 32bit and 64bit code. Good luck!

Comment: gog thanks for your repply, trying here but this is a language form another planet for me jaja, anyway trying.
Question, what about  https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net
that c code can be converted to detours.net  ?

Comment: Trying to learn but this   require high knowledge of c++/cli etc.
Nothing I test work and only have large list of errors i just not understand, as a Frank, I trying to make this work form year 2013  with no success  :(

Comment: @MrBi you don't need 7 years to learn C++/CLI and mixed-mode DLLs. You can do that in some months. Once you are ready, come back here and use my answer to get your desired results. Should you have problems, simply create a new question, detailing the code you used and the problems you met.
On my part, I can assure you that this code works and is being used in at least one production app.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi GOG, I have this finally working, mouse not jump to position where I touch. There is a  problem I want fix. 
I wnat mouse cursor wont disappear on touch down and on touch move. Some idea why cursor disappear from the screen until I stop use the touch?

Comment: @MrBi that's another question. Open it, detail what you want to achieve, what is the actual result, and what you tried to overcome the differences.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class PreventTouchToMousePromotion
{

    public static void Register(FrameworkElement root)
    {
        root.PreviewMouseDown += Evaluate;
        root.PreviewMouseMove += Evaluate;
        root.PreviewMouseUp += Evaluate;
    }

    private static void Evaluate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.StylusDevice != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Excample Usage:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PreventTouchToMousePromotion.Register(this);
    }
```

or take a look at this post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b05e550-19c0-46a2-b19c-40f40c8bf0ec/prevent-a-wpf-application-to-interpret-touch-events-as-mouse-events?forum=wpf#9965f159-04a4-41ed-b199-30394991f120

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. It does filter out mouse move messages for my application. So far so good. But the mouse pointer still moves when the screen is touched.

Comment: I'm beginning to think, that the TouchFrameEventArgs.SuspendMousePromotionUntilTouchUp Method would not do much more than this proposal.