# Why is RoutedEventArgs.Handled ignored between TouchDown and Click

Tags: wpf, touch

I am trying to support both `TouchDown` and `Click` with the same event.

You will notice that the following code, instead of toggling between green and red, just flashes red and goes back to green. As far as I can tell, this is because the click event is ignoring the `Handled` property of the `RoutedEvent`. I need this to work with both Touch and Mouse.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CodeSpace.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="LightGreen">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Touch Me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="75" Width="75" Click="OnClick" TouchDown="OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CodeSpace.WPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Background = (Background.Equals(Brushes.LightGreen)) ? Brushes.LightCoral : Brushes.LightGreen;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the reason I am not just using `Click` alone (which is supposed to work with `Touch`) is because with my specific case when I do that, the first time the button is touched nothing happens. All subsequent touches work just fine. This is a separate issue that I can't ask about because I cannot reproduce it in a simple code example. Also, this behavior only happens when windows is set to 120 DPI. Everything works just fine in 96 DPI. I have no idea!

Answer (score 0):

The click event comes as a result of MouseUp/TouchUp rather than *Down (unless you change the ClickBehavior of the button).  This answer has a good approach to globally blocking the promotion of mouse events to touch events for an element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540120/518955