# How to reset mouse cursor position c#

Tags: c#, windows, mouse, multiple-monitors

**Working Environment** 
I working on automobile feedback project which work on dual monitor in extended mode.
Screen 1(Non Touch) - Customer Care Executive working screen
Screen 2(Touch)     - Customer feedback software running on this screen, which work only on touch no keyboard input.

**Problem** 
When customer click on screen 2 for feedback, cursor position changed from screen 1 to screen 2 which disturb customer care executive.

**Proposed Solution**
Can i run background timer thread which checks cursor position after 1 or 2 milliseconds if its on screen 2 it will bring it back on by resetting cursor position.

**What i want**- Is it possible when customer click on screen 2 it perform click operation over there and bring back focus to last active control on screen 1 which can be textbox, window etc.

**Questions Regarding above Solution**

- Will mouse click will be done in 1 or 2 milliseconds time period.
- How can i restore focus to last active control on screen 1.
- My main motive is not to disturb screen 1 executive working as customer screen will active on mouse click only for few milliseconds.

Edit - Can [Multipoint mouse sdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff877472.aspx) help me?

Comment: is there any event on screen 2? like button click to submit feedback , if so than u can just set the cursor position to screen 1 on click of submit button. 
if there is no button click event on screen 2 , you can check for the idle time at screen 2, its more than 3 second than just pass the cursor to screen 1.

Comment: yeah i have buttons on screen 2 which can solve above issue, but how will i identify which was the last active control on screen 1, so that control can be focused back.

Comment: you dint mention that you have different controls on screen 1, 
so , for this you can write a call back function for each control  which will wait for button click event to triggered or else in 3 seconds it will drop the call and set the current control as focused.

Comment: @Friyank i want one system multiple user environment for above problem. On second screen only feedback software will run but on screen 1 user can do any task.

Comment: hmm 2 users, 1 PC. what OS is it running on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010104/how-to-avoid-mouse-move-on-touch

Comment: @Ewan i am using windows 7

Comment: @Ewan above link will not help as it only hide cursor movement. Focus get changed on each click.

Comment: I dont think you are going to find a good solution to this. you are fighting the OS which assumes one program has focus at any given time. An easy solution would be to have two PCs.

Comment: Or possibly you could use a custom touch driver and not pass the touches to windows?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I made this, based on code from vbfox / ulatekh:

https://gist.github.com/Fredi/f245fbec9c8ae3c66c3a4034c7cf8f85

It disables touch to mouse conversions but forwards button click events only.

```
// Based on ulatekh's code: https://gist.github.com/ulatekh/f37b1a973c7a1b09f18a457e3a4af54a
// I wanted to keep the funcionality but allow button clicks on the touch screen monitor,
// that way the main user can start a customer feedback window in the touch screen and be able
// to keep working in the main screen without interference from the touch screen.
namespace BlackFox
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    /// <summary>
    /// As long as this object exists all mouse events created from a touch event for legacy support will be disabled.
    /// Or, at least, that's the promise. But the system mouse-cursor still gets set to the position of the last
    /// touch-event, and so far, there seems to be no way to prevent that.
    /// </summary>
    class DisableTouchConversionToMouse : IDisposable
    {
        // The window on which to disable the conversion of touch-events to
        // mouse-events (including all of its child windows).
        // If null, conversion is disabled globally.
        private IntPtr m_hWnd;

        // The installed hook-callbacks.
        private HookProc hookCallback, hookCallbackLL;
        private IntPtr hookId, hookIdLL;

        // Disable touch-conversion globally.
        public DisableTouchConversionToMouse()
            : this(IntPtr.Zero)
        {
        }

        // Disable touch-conversion for a single window (including all its child windows).
        public DisableTouchConversionToMouse(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            // Remember the window on which to disable event-conversion, if any.
            m_hWnd = hWnd;

            // Install both styles of mouse hooks.
            // Save a reference to the callback, so that it doesn't get
            // garbage-collected.
            hookCallback = this.HookCallback;
            hookId = SetHook(hookCallback);
            hookCallbackLL = this.HookCallbackLL;
            hookIdLL = SetHookLL(hookCallbackLL);
        }

        // Set a WH_MOUSE callback.
        static IntPtr SetHook(HookProc proc)
        {
            var moduleHandle = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(null);
            var threadHandle = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId();

            var setHookResult = UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, proc, moduleHandle, threadHandle);
            if (setHookResult == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            return setHookResult;
        }

        // Set a WH_MOUSE_LL callback.
        static IntPtr SetHookLL(HookProc proc)
        {
            var moduleHandle = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(null);

            var setHookResult = UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, moduleHandle, 0);
            if (setHookResult == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            return setHookResult;
        }

        // The WH_MOUSE callback.
        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                var info = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT));

                // Determine whether this mouse-event was generated from a touch event.
                // Fix for 64-bit Windows found in a comment from giangurgolo at the
                // end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8012213 .
                bool bMouseEventFromTouch = false;
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    var extraInfo = (uint)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt32();
                    if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                    {
                        bMouseEventFromTouch = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                {
                    var extraInfo = (ulong)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt64();
                    if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                    {
                        bMouseEventFromTouch = true;
                    }
                }

                if (bMouseEventFromTouch)
                {
                    // If we weren't initialized with a window-handle, then
                    // converting touch-events to mouse events is disabled
                    // for all windows.
                    if (m_hWnd == null)
                        return new IntPtr(1);

                    if ((int)wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
                    {
                        var button = Control.FromHandle(info.hwnd) as Button;
                        if (button != null)
                        {
                            button.PerformClick();
                            return new IntPtr(1);
                        }
                    }

                    // Otherwise, disable converting touch-events to mouse events
                    // for the given window, and all its child windows.
                    IntPtr hwnd = info.hwnd;
                    while (hwnd != null)
                    {
                        if (hwnd == m_hWnd)
                            return new IntPtr(1);
                        hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
                    }
                }
            }

            return UnsafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        // The WH_MOUSE_LL callback.
        private IntPtr HookCallbackLL(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                var info = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

                // Determine whether this mouse-event was generated from a touch event.
                // Fix for 64-bit Windows found in a comment from giangurgolo at the
                // end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8012213 .
                bool bMouseEventFromTouch = false;
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    var extraInfo = (uint)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt32();
                    if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                    {
                        bMouseEventFromTouch = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                {
                    var extraInfo = (ulong)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt64();
                    if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                    {
                        bMouseEventFromTouch = true;
                    }
                }

                if (bMouseEventFromTouch)
                {
                    // If we weren't initialized with a window-handle, then
                    // converting touch-events to mouse events is disabled
                    // for all windows.
                    if (m_hWnd == null)
                        return new IntPtr(1);

                    IntPtr hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(info.pt);

                    if ((int)wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
                    {
                        var button = Control.FromHandle(hwnd) as Button;
                        if (button != null)
                        {
                            button.PerformClick();
                            return new IntPtr(1);
                        }
                    }

                    // Otherwise, disable converting touch-events to mouse events
                    // for the given window, and all its child windows.
                    while (hwnd != null)
                    {
                        if (hwnd == m_hWnd)
                            return new IntPtr(1);
                        hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetParent(hwnd);
                    }
                }
            }

            return UnsafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hookIdLL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        bool disposed;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed) return;

            UnsafeNativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
            UnsafeNativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookIdLL);
            disposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ~DisableTouchConversionToMouse()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        #region Interop

        // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        // ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Local
        // ReSharper disable FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local

        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH = 0xFF515700;
        const int WH_MOUSE = 7;
        const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public uint wHitTestCode;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        static class UnsafeNativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod,
                uint dwThreadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
                IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT p);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
        }

        // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
        // ReSharper restore FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Local
        // ReSharper restore MemberCanBePrivate.Local

        #endregion
    }
}
```