# c# LowLevelMouseProc， Prevent Touch event Conversion To Mouse event

Tags: c#, windows, hook, mouse, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors, one of which is a touch screen device. I want to prevent the mouse from moving to the touch screen device when a touch event is triggered.

So , I use Hook_LL

> As long as this object exists all mouse events created from a touch event for legacy support will be disabled. Or, at least, that's the promise. **But the system mouse-cursor still gets set to the position of the last touch-event, and so far, there seems to be no way to prevent that.**

```cs
        static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                var info = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                
                // 64-bit 
                var extraInfo = (ulong)info.dwExtraInfo.ToInt64();
                if ((extraInfo & MOUSEEVENTF_MASK) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH)
                {
                    // Prevent Touch -> Mouse Event message delivery.
                    return new IntPtr(1); // if ((extraInfo & 0x80) != 0) is Touch Input,other is Pen Input.
                }
            }
            
            return UnsafeNativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

I use `GetCursorPos` that the scheme was effective, even though the mouse disappeared.

Unfortunately, when the `touch down` is triggered, I don't move the mouse, just click the left mouse button, but `click down` is still triggered on the touch screen device.

Although I can disable `click down` triggering on the touch screen device, I want to respond to `click down` at the position of the mouse.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I hope that after clicking the touch screen button, when clicking with the mouse, the click event will respond to the original position instead of the button on the touch screen.

[How to reset mouse cursor position c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982720/how-to-reset-mouse-cursor-position-c-sharp/38187269#38187269)

[How to avoid mouse move on Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010104/how-to-avoid-mouse-move-on-touch)

Comment: If you call [RegisterTouchWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) no compatibility mouse messages are generated for that window. Though it's not entirely clear what problem you are ultimately trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable sry , I have re-described my problem.